# My sql workbench show query on apply

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I had installed older version of mySql workbench. Now I have updated to 6.1 .

Earlier when we update something and clicks on apply it showed update statement to be executed, but this version does not do that.

I have tried checking `Edit->preferences->SQL Queries: Confirm Data changes.`, still no wizard. I need to **save the update query** to apply on other instance of DB too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you would hit a bug with latest workbench:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72155

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72169

Comment: Oh right, this is a known bug, I need to downgrade mysql workbench.

Comment: Yes. Or you can try other GUI clients like SQLyog or Navicat. But those are commercial products.